# Where are there examples of the XlRangeAutoFormat enumeration?

Tags: c#, office-interop, excel-2010

I'm new to doing **Office interop** via C#/.NET. In the Excel API there is a *Range.AutoFormat()* command that takes an enummeration of **xlRangeAutoFormat**. The names of the enumeration don't correspond to the Excel *Format As Table* options in Excel 2010. In Excel you have categories of names like *Light*, *Medium*, *Dark*, in the enumeration you have many options with names like *xlRangeAutoFormatClassic2*. Does anyone know of a reference that shows what these enumerations look like? If not is there a way in Excel to use these enumerations manually to find a suitable one?

Comment: I'm not after just the Classic2 Format I would like to see what they all look like and then pick one. There appear to be about 50. I get the feeling I may end up writing code that generates all 50 samples but it would be nice to not waste the time if there are examples somewhere.

Comment: Yes, please don't hesitate to post screen-shots of what it looks like.  That's what this site is all about.  I'm curious a bit about what "Classic2" looks like.  Imagining bright white on dark blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a method to apply all the enums with a pause of 2 seconds on each one showing the int conversion of the enum and a shortened version of the name. [I made the world's most boring video out of it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XITybmWnmLc) and put it on youtube. Many of the enums do nothing as far as I can tell, many are ugly. I can see why examples aren't available probably no one is formatting their tables using the auto formats.

And here's the famous classic2[image]